# Cohomological dimension and height of ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-cohomology, noetherian

Let $I$ be an ideal in a Noetherian ring $R$. We define the cohomological dimension of $I$ to be $\operatorname{cd}(I)=\operatorname{sup}\{i\in \mathbb N:\operatorname{H}_I^i(R)\neq0\}$ and it is known that $\operatorname{height}(I)\leq \operatorname{cd}(I)$. I would like to know when one can conclude that $\operatorname{height}(I)= \operatorname{cd}(I)$? In particular, is it true that if $R$ is a regular local ring and $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then $\operatorname{height}(I)= \operatorname{cd}(I)$?